# Unable to convert instance of type 'Android.Support.V7.Widget.AppCompatTextView' to type 'Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar' android 7.0

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

i'm running an application in Device and just got this error when run in Android 7.0

I'm using this versions:

[image]

My xamarin version is:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>

  <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
  </style>
  <!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
  <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without android:-->
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
    <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
    <!-- Set theme colors from http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette -->
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#39b549</item>
    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#4d4d4d</item>
    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
         which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#4d4d4d</item>
    <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
         colorControlHighlight and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>

    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#39b549</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
  </style>

  <style name="MyTheme.Splash" parent ="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen_jpg</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

I dont know what cause this erro, even know where to found more things to give.
On others version of android is runing fine.

Comment: Are you using XF to develop your app? did you modify the `Toolbar.axml` file in Android project? Please show the layout of your `Toolbar`.

Comment: I have created an Issue on component page, if u could check.
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidSupportComponents/issues/58